# How to change the width of #side_bar_container?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have tried all the selectors but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I'm trying to select the `#side_bar_container` and change it to `width:50px` when hovering over `#line_container1`.

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#side_bar_container {
    width:350px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 214);
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    transition:.5s;
}
.line_container {
    height:50px;
    background-color: #555C66;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.line_image {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.line_text {
    margin-top: 16px; /* Depends on other values */
    font-size:18px;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#logo {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
}
.sidebar_loader {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    display: ; /*very very important*/
    z-index: -3;
    position: absolute; /* Works with fixed - absolute is experimental */
    left: 50px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(69,75,83);
}
/* The power starts here */
#line_container1:hover {
    background-color: rgb(69,75,83);
}
#line_container2:hover {
    background-color: rgb(69,75,83);
}
#line_container3:hover {
    background-color: rgb(69,75,83);
}
#sidebar_loader1:hover #line_container1 {
    background-color: red;
}
/*more*/
#line_container1:hover + #side_bar_container {
    width:5000px;
}
#line_container1:hover ~ #sidebar_loader1 {
    z-index: -2;
}
#line_container2:hover ~ #sidebar_loader2 {
    z-index: -2;
}
#line_container3:hover ~ #sidebar_loader3 {
    z-index: -2;
}
#sidebar_loader1 ~ #line_container1:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>side bar</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="side_bar_container">
        <img src="" alt="image" id="logo" />
        <div class="line_container" id="line_container1">
            <img src="http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/png.png" alt="IMAGE" class="line_image" />
            <span class="line_text">THIS IS SOME SAMPLE TEXT ></span>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar_loader" id="sidebar_loader1">TEST for 1</div>
        <div class="line_container"  id="line_container2">
            <img src="http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/png.png" alt="IMAGE" class="line_image" />
            <span class="line_text">THIS IS SOME SAMPLE TEXT ></span>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar_loader" id="sidebar_loader2">TEST for 2</div>
        <div class="line_container"  id="line_container3">
            <img src="http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/png.png" alt="IMAGE" class="line_image">
            <span class="line_text">THIS IS SOME SAMPLE TEXT ></span>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar_loader" id="sidebar_loader3">TEST for 3</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS.

Comment: i know i left it as that because nothing work. please can you tell me what to do

Comment: I know how to do it in javascript but i need to do it in css only

Comment: all i am trying to do is #side_bar_container:hover ~ #line_container1 {width:50px;}. but this doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible through only css because we cant select parent of any html tag.
`#side_bar_container` is parent of `#line_container1`.

Comment: are you sure there isnt anyway.